# Sencha touch 2 : List shows only last item retrieved from API

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I want to show the data from the following API in List :

http://customer.appxtream.com/astro.apps.cms/jsonFeed.action/?service=astroSportsDataService&action=grabJsonText&mimeType=application/json&p1=HighlightNewsList&p2=EURO2012

when I get the data, the Network of Chrome shows me that all elements have been retrieved but List shows only the data from the last item in the API  here is my code:

---

**View**

```javascript
Ext.define('astro.view.HighliteNews', {
    extend: 'Ext.DataView',
    xtype: 'highliteNews',
    config:{

        title:'xren',
        store: 'highliteNewsStoreId',
        itemtap: true,
        scrollable:'horizontal',
        inline:{
            wrap:false
        },

        itemTpl:[
             '<div><img src="{imageLink}"/> </div>',
        ],
    },
});
```

---

**Store**

```javascript
Ext.define('astro.store.HighliteNewsStore',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    xtype:'highliteNewsStore',

    config:{
        model: 'astro.model.HighliteNewsModel',
        autoLoad: true,
        storeId: 'highliteNewsStoreId',

        proxy:{
            type:'ajax',

           url :'http://customer.appxtream.com/astro.apps.cms/jsonFeed.action',

            extraParams:{
                service:'astroSportsDataService',
                action:'grabJsonText',
                p1:'HighlightNewsList',
                p2:'EURO2012',
                mimeType:'application/json'

            },

            reader:{
                type:'json',
                rootProperty:'cmsHighlightNewsList',
            },

        },
    }
});
```

---

**Model**

```javascript
Ext.define('astro.model.HighliteNewsModel',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config:{
        fields: ['imageLink'],

    }
});
```

---

So the network shows that 3 images are sent from API but the List shows ONLY LAST IMAGE.
Please help

Comment: your link is not working man...

Comment: well, If I enter the link in browser, I get all data, so it means it is working, even when I open the Network section in Chrome, I can see that all data are retrieved.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem guys :) , there is an conflict between Sencha and JsonP, so if you assign a idproperty to your Model, the problem will be sloved :

```
config:{
    idProperty: 'HighliteIdProperty',
    fields: ['imageLink'],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things I would suggest :

**Add a listener to the load event of the store**

This is just to check that all the data is load in your store.
You can do it in different ways :

In a controller

```
store.on({
  load:function(){
    console.log(store.getCount());
  }
});
```

or directly in the store config with the listeners attribute

```
listeners:{
  load:function(store){
    console.log(store.getCount());
  }
}
```

**Check the DOM**

In the Web Inspector / Firebug, check if your items are there or only the last one.

I think you could also try this command in the console :

```
Ext.DomQuery.select('div[class=x-dataview-item]').length
```

It will return the number of items in your dataview.

**Set a width and height to your image**

I also had the same problem with a dynamically loaded dataview. All the picture were there in the DOM but too small to be seen. So I suggest, you give them a CSS class with a defined width and height.

That's all I can think of for now.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you guys, the problem is not the size of images, bcuz it happens for the other fields also,
I put that listener also, but I get nothing in console, NO error, no message, no thing ...

Comment: I also added Ext.DomQuery.select('div[class=x-dataview-item]').length to console and I get "1", that is only 1 item is there

Comment: I solved the problem guys, there is an conflict between Sencha and JsonP, so if you assign a idproperty to your store, the problem will be sloved :

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Arash for this question and answer. We are facing similar problem and found that we didn't have model defined. Defining the model worked in our case. However, it worked while we retrieved playlist from youtube and now while retrieving the list from google spreadsheet. Hope this helps others who are using google spreadsheet.

Answer (score -2):

adjust the height in the config of view......this might be a problem

Comment: I downvoted because this answer is really poor and provide no explanation at all. Plus, he's apparently working on a horizontal list so I don't think adjusting the height would change anything.